# Как ускорить чтение данных из БД или сократить число запросов?

Tags: база-данных, django, оптимизация, redis, nosql

Проект на Django/REST-Framework/PostgreSQL.

Имеются модели, связанные преимущественно one-to-many, и API, которое совершает запросы к БД.

Сейчас происходит около 700-1500 запросов к БД при загрузке некоторых страниц, БД растет и дальше будет хуже. В какую сторону смотреть для решения проблем?

Править существующий код/использовать сырые запросы? Как понимаю, это временное решение и мы снова упремся в потолок.

Хранилища типа "ключ-значение" - Redis/memcached и тп? Но тут, как я тоже предполагаю, есть потолок при росте данных и мы должны менять структуру проекта.

В поисках решение увидел еще один способ - блочное чтение из БД. Поясните про него. Можем ли мы использовать его при построение API? Например, отдавать данные постепенно, вплоть до одной записи и передавать их потребителю? Можем ли совместить использование блочного чтение и key-value хранилища?

Какие еще замечания есть по указанным способам и что я не учитываю?

---

Добавил часть кода, для понимания. Имеются две связанные модели. Первой соответствуют 120 записей в таблице, второй - больше 10000 (примерно по 100 объектов Property на Element)

```js
class Element(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(verbose_name="Name", max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Element"
        verbose_name_plural = "Elements"


class Property(models.Model):
    element = ForeignKey(Element, related_name='properties')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=TYPE)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Property"
        verbose_name_plural = "Properties"
        ordering = ('title',)
```

От API получаю следующую структуру - нужна выборка из определенных строк таблицы `property`

```html
[
    {
        "name": "Lithium",
        "properties": {
            "group": "1",
            "atomic_number": "3",
            "symbol": "Li",
            "period": "2",
            "atomic_weight": "6.941",
            "type": "alkali"
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "Beryllium",
        "properties": {
            "group": "2",
            "atomic_number": "4",
            "symbol": "Be",
            "period": "2",
            "atomic_weight": "9.012182",
            "type": "alkaline"
        }
    }


   ...
```

В одном из методов я использую запросы вида (obj - объект модели Element)

```js
def get_properties(self, obj):
        properties = ['Symbol', 'Group', 'Period', 'Type', 'Atomic weight', 'Atomic number']
        func = lambda property: obj.properties.get(title=property).value if obj.properties.filter(title=property).exists() else None
        data = map(func, properties)

        return dict(zip(properties, data))
```

Вот проверка в этой функции удваивает число запросов к базе, убираем проверку - число запросов падает в два раза, как обойти не пойму

```
 func = lambda property: obj.properties.get(title=property).value if obj.properties.filter(title=property).exists() else None
```

Comment: вам нужно переписывать приложение, k/v хранилища здесь просто мертвому припарки.

Comment: @etki добавил кусок кода, который смущает меня и не пойму как его переписать

Comment: Я никогда при использовании PostgreSQL не использую абстракцию модели - зачем это? Ведь база данных в виде набора таблиц, связей и правил целостности уже является моделью. А SQL - достаточно высокого уровня язык запросов для взаимодействия с моделью. Зачем вам модель-то?? Модель надо использовать когда данные собираются фиг знает откуда - из файлов каких-то или старых дубовых версий mysql.

Comment: @EugeneBartosh я использую фреймворк джанго, там модели используются для создания и управления таблицами

Comment: и что вам мешает не использовать модели? я использую Zend и Symphony, там тоже модели, но я на них просто помещаю болт в 9 из 10 случаев, PgSQL не подводит

Comment: @EugeneBartosh ничего, только нужно будет писать больше кода и еще куча нюансов. Django ORM связывает модели и принципы ООП https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/models/

Comment: ну я не знаток Django, но думаю всегда можно создать некую абстрактную модель, которая ничего не делает, только выполняет SQL-запросы. Если вы не можете обойти неудобные вам правила фреймворка - то у меня лично вопрос зачем он нужен такой, просто любопытно :-)

Comment: @EugeneBartosh потому что пока другого не знаю) а api писать нужно. так модель не выполняет никакие запросы, она просто создает таблицу в БД.  их делаю я, и получается слишком много обращений

Comment: @EugeneBartosh и применительно к вашему ответу "выбрать всех людей в возрасте от 20 до 30 лет" одним запросом. а если будет счет строк на тысячи или десятки тысяч? у нас памяти не хватит, что тогда делать?

Comment: используйте что хотите, только не нужно на запрос генерить 1500 обращений к бд ;-) некоторые системы вообще не пропустят код, у которого в цикле SQL-запросы встречаются - низя. Надо сначала в программе всё собрать в кучку, сформировать SQL и выполнить его 1 раз, чаще всего нужен 1 SQL-запрос на 1 запрос к контроллеру

Comment: @while1pass у меня - хватит ;-) вообще нетрудно посчитать сколько у вас памяти и какого размера таблицы, я сомневаюсь что настолько большие (иначе бы вы более грустный рассказ про свою супер-пупер программу с 1500 запросами на 1 клик рассказывали бы ;-) Но если действительно большие - нужно ограничивать выборку - limit и offset использовать

Comment: кстати, в том же salesforce.com ограничивается также количество записей, которые от базы данных может принять программа за 1 ее выполнение, типа 100.000 записей :-) Логичный вопрос - а зачем такие выборки на контроллер перекидывать? Чтобы вернуть пользователю - никогда в жизни ему столько за раз не нужно, если контроллер что-то считает и потом возвращает пользователю агрегат - так лучше сразу агрегат у базы данных попросить грамотным SQL-ем, просто вот жесть  - откуда такие цифры, даже 1500 записей на контроллере это оч много

Comment: выглядит, как будто где-то пропущен джойн. но про k/v модель забираю лова назад, если у вас на самом деле просто выводится таблица менделеева - имеет смысл завести отдельную таблицу, в котороую запихивать уже готовые сущности в json или иной форме сериализации и доставать по ключу.

Comment: @etki спасибо, я уже оптимизировал ситуацию до приемлимых для меня 100-130 запросов, позже буду смотреть в стороку кв-хранилищ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мне кажется тут проблема скорее с неправильным построением запросов и архитектурой, чем серьезные проблемы с производительностью базы данных.

700-1500 запросов на одну страницу это непомерно много. Уверен количество запросов можно значительно уменьшить.

Например если взять метод, который вы привели в пример:

```
def get_properties(self, obj):
    properties = ['Symbol', 'Group', 'Period', 'Type', 'Atomic weight', 'Atomic number']
    func = lambda property: obj.properties.get(title=property).value if obj.properties.filter(title=property).exists() else None
    data = map(func, properties)

    return dict(zip(properties, data))
```

У меня за 10 минут получилось переписать его так, чтобы он использовал только одно обращение к базе:

```
def get_properties(self, obj):
    titles = ['Symbol', 'Group', 'Period', 'Type', 'Atomic weight', 'Atomic number']
    props = {p.title: p.value for p in obj.properties.filter(title__in=properties).values('title', 'value')}
    data = {title: None for title in titles}
    data.update(props)
    return data
```

Уверен, что подобных мест в вашем коде не так уж и мало и значительного улучшения производительности можно добиться просто переписав их так, чтобы они не генерировали лишние запросы, не пересчитывали лишний раз то, что уже посчитано и т.д.

Comment: Спасибо за полезный совет! Я уже оптимизировал, но ваш метод гораздо изящнее, правда, не пойму зачем использовать промежуточный словарь data. Метод может состоять из одной строки, не считая списка titles: props = {p.title.lower().replace(' ', '_'): p.value for p in obj.properties.filter(title__in=titles)}

Answer (score 0):

В современных Cloud-системах, и в добрых старых mainframe-системах, существуют ограничения на количество запросов из программы пользователя. Если программа пользователя лимиты превышает - она отбрыкивается без разговора. Типичные ограничения - 150 SQL-запросов + 100 DML-запросов. 
Также существуют ограничения на количество запросов в триггерах, но это отдельная тема.

При загрузке страницы количество запросов не может быть больше какого-то разумного числа, обычно оно <10. Если у вас 1500 - это не попадает вообще ни в какие критерии и пора ставить вопросы к разработчикам, которые так усердно эти запросы плодят :-)

Ну сами посудите - ведь можно выбрать всех людей в возрасте от 20 до 30 лет одним запросом, а можно за каждым из них отдельным запросом сбегать... зачем отдельным если можно всех сразу?

Comment: ни разу не видел ограничение на количество запросов в "современных cloud-системах", только pay-per-request/pay-for-network модели

Comment: Дык посмотрите - есть во всех

Comment: Не поверите, только что с compose.io и лэндинга google cloud sql

Comment: добавил код, который плодит запросы, как обойти не пойму

Comment: @etki такие ограничения характерны для бизнес-систем с оплатой по подписке - например, salesforce.com, SAP (в cloud- и не-cloud вариантах)

Comment: @EugeneBartosh salesforce торгует sql-запросами? Вот ведь новость.

Comment: @etki не-а, говору ж по подписке :-)

Comment: Тогда я не понимаю, зачем вы утверждаете о существовании указанной модели применимо к бд.

Comment: @etki эти правила применимы к любой системе коллективного пользования, это просто требования хорошего стиля программирования

Comment: есть некоторая разница между "правила хорошего тона" и "она отбрыкивается без разговора"

Comment: @etki отбрыкивать по такому принципу можете вы сами - например тест-методы обязательные добавить с проверкой на такое :-) отбрыкивать можно опять же программу, или программиста с работы вместе с его программой ;-)